# Android Tree view type control that can also support controls like button and image view etc?

Tags: android, xml, treeview, controls

i have been searching for control like tree view that also support control in it. But i have not found any usefull thing except link,

https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

how can i do my required things as i mentioned in also viewable in pic attached[image]

when i click it open like tree view i can have control like tab or button as shown in pic but would have also control inside that open when we click

Or i will have to do it on design mode ? any example will be appreciable

Hope sfor your suggestion thanks in advance